# WordPress Adding Placeholder to Login Inputs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to add placeholders to a theme for WordPress, I have a custom javascript file being loaded correctly (http://prntscr.com/89vc99).
the `function.php` (http://prntscr.com/89vd6m)

and the script looks like this: however nothing changes I tried checking the `console.log` and get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   dc-script.js:4

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user_login').attr( 'placeholder', 'Username' );
  $('#user_pass').attr( 'placeholder', 'Password' );
});
```

I assume that WordPress is loading jQuery before my script if thats maybe the problem? otherwise is this correct or is there something else wrong?

UPDATE: added this to my `functions.php` as well as changing $ to jQuery in the js script file, this has solved the problem.

```
//Making jQuery Google API
function modify_jquery() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
    }

add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Comment: Try jQuery instead of $.

Comment: tried this didnt work =(

Comment: Then you need to include jQuery. http://jquery.com/

Comment: jquery is already loaded, the theme is based off foundationpress which is already loading jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code hopefully it work for you.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#user_login').attr( "placeholder", "Username" );
    jQuery('#user_pass').attr( "placeholder", "Password" );
 });
```

or you can add following code in function.php.

```
   add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'placeholder', 10 );
   function placeholder() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri()'/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), 1.0 );
      }
```

add this below code to script.js file

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#user_login').attr( "placeholder", "Username" );
    jQuery('#user_pass').attr( "placeholder", "Password" );
 });
```

Comment: Ok working now had to deregister and register the jquery like you mentioned as well as changing the $ to jQuery (out of curiousity why doesnt the shortform $ work, why does it need to be jQuery written out? Thanks for the help)

Comment: when we Include jquery we use syntax like this `$('.class').attr()` if jquery not include then we use `jQuery('.class').attr();`

Answer (score 0):

that means you dont have jquery un your theme.
you must first download the [latest version of jquery](https://jquery.com/download/)  and then place file in js folder of your theme. then register it in *functions.php* :

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

and then enqueue jquery:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/js/jquery.js", '', '1.11.2');
```